# Jointer setup gives bow on the board

Tags: jointer

I recently bought my first jointer and I set it up according to several tutorial videos online. My knives are slightly above the outfeed table, and I used a ruler to see how many millimetres is the ruler moved. It's moved by 3mm.

[image]

I used this method to check the knives.

EDIT1: tutorials I followed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvbfdzkPPSg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2u8OAS8-xJY&t=241s

https://www.woodmagazine.com/tool-reviews/joiners-planers/setting-jointer-knives-2

https://woodgears.ca/jointer/knives.html

However I'm getting a slight bow at the centre of the the board.

You can see the bow at the photos below. I planed two edges on two boards and they do not touch perfectly. I get the same bow on the faces of the board.

My opinion is that the tables on the planer are too small. The planer tables are 150 cm long (infeed 75cm and outfeed 75cm) but I could be wrong. Could this be just wrong technique? I apply small pressure just after the cutting head on an outfeed table.

Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For those on the other side of the pond, 150cm = 60". That seems like plenty of in- and out-feed table length. How long is the board you're planing?

Comment: The boards are 170cm long.

Comment: Just a note that planing to a slight concavity  is a trick used by jointers for centuries because once clamped up it makes a nice glue joint.

Comment: So by sheer luck I got it right? However I would like this to avoid on a face of a board.

Comment: You could back off from the 3mm drop and see if that works better for you.

Comment: @jdv, yes, very relevant point. But as the OP immediately jumped to, it's something you want to avoid on the face of a board. [Very very much want to avoid.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Could you list some or all of the 'several' videos you used here so people can know the source(s) of this advice please. And BTW, yes, you definitely need more outfeed support for long boards if the infeed and outfeed tables *together* measure 150cm; could you clarify that, in case it's 150cm each, rather than combined.

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see the tutorials I use, also you can see the size of my tables.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!

Comment: @Graphus no doubt, but as usual I didn't _read_ the Q. But it had pretty pictures of two edges that would joint beautifully!

Comment: (Also, should we really be using a _jointer_ for _surfacing_? I mean, it'll work more or less, and getting a flat surface square with an adjacent edge is what jointing is all about. But some kind of surfacing tool is better for... surfacing.)

Comment: @jdv, good point that the jointer may not be the last tool to see the face of a board (although it can be). But if a cupped face is generated it could cause issues on a later step, same as snipe can. And bottom line I think must be that a jointer IS supposed to produce dead-flat faces or edges if set up and used correctly.

Comment: @Graphus, agreed. It's easy enough to take that dead flat edge and hand plane a concavity if you need it. Ideally this tool should be able to make square and true pieces to reasonable tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

> My knives are slightly above the outfeed table

As I suspected they would be, the Wood Magazine instructions are correct, but you missed one critical detail in the wording:

*When the knife moves the block about 1⁄8", as shown, **without lifting it off the table**, you have the correct knife-height setting.*

I know this is directly contradicted by one or more of your other sources but listen to the following passing reference in [this](https://youtu.be/OQIcLWPtFcw?t=147) Fine Woodworking video (on shimming a jointer's outfeed table to fix sagging).

Comment: Thanks, yes the ruler on my table does elevate. I'll try setting it up so it wont elevate